# Python tooling around EOS

Tags: python

I am looking to integrate EOS to Python based command line tooling and server side backends.

As EOS is young project and information is still dispersed, I am looking for more insight than a Google search what kind of Python toolchains and utilities there exist for EOS at the moment?

Notably I found this project for testing and deploying smart contracts - http://eosfactory.io/sphinx/build/html/ - I ideally would like to run py.test based end-to-end test suites against my smart contract codebase.

Comment: there is this python wrapper for eosjs: https://github.com/EvaCoop/eosjs_python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into github to answer your question and found a very interesting project.

https://github.com/learnforpractice/pyeos

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to use EOS rpc APIs by python. So, I started with my own wrapper for python. This is the [link](https://github.com/r12543/pyeos).

It is in very early stage. If you want to contribute, you are very welcome.

When we push a transaction from command line, it requires only one command but while using rpc APIs you have to make multiple request to push a transaction. So, for that I have written a separate class where you can push a transaction using only one function. Do try that and let me know your views.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to `JavaHead1560`'s answer by recommending the use of `shlex` package, which correctly deals with cases with quoted contents inside `command`.

```
import shlex, json
import subprocess
from subprocess 

def do_cmd(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(command))

info = json.loads(do_cmd("cleos system buyram account1 account2 '1 EOS' -j"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run the different programs (cleos/nodeos/keosd) in python like you can run any other command:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import smtplib
from subprocess import PIPE

def do_cmd(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command.split(" "))
do_cmd("cleos -u http://mainnet.genereos.io get info")
```

Alternatively here's a link to the API documentation: 
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_info