# How to start learning EOS with python?

Tags: python

As a programmer with a python background, how do I get started with EOS?

Are there any EOS resources for python developers?

Comment: Please have a look at the official documentation or do a little google research... https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/tutorials/exchange-tutorial-python

Comment: This is just a script that interfaces with `cleos` via Python's `subprocess` module. I assumed the OP was looking for something nontrivial, for instance some library/API on either the client side or the smart-contract development side. Also see https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/490/python-tooling-around-eos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is/will be possible to generate smart contracts via Python and other languages, an example [here](https://github.com/learnforpractice/pyeos).

However, the mainstream method, especially in the early days, is with C++, as per the [EOS Developer documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/required-knowledge)

> "Other toolchains in development by 3rd parties include: Rust, Python, and Solidity. While these other languages might appear simpler, their performance will likely impact the scale of application you can build. We expect that C++ will be the best language for developing high-performance and secure smart contracts, and plan to use C++ for the foreseeable future."

I suggest learning C++ even if it's a bit more intimidating than Python. Microsoft do some [EdX courses](https://www.edx.org/learn/c) on it.

Learning C++ is a safe bet for working with other EOS developers as well I'd say and not being isolated when adopting code from existing libraries based in C++.

Answer (score 1):

commands like cleos/nodeos/keosd can be run from a python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import smtplib
from subprocess import PIPE

def do_cmd(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command.split(" "))
do_cmd("cleos -u http://mainnet.genereos.io get info")
```

Alternatively there's a handy API that uses POST requests. Check this out: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_info